# Simpler implementation of the Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation

I know there are very simple ways to generate all possible permutations of characters in a string, especially recursively, but I found a very clear description [here](https://tropenhitze.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/steinhaus-johnson-trotter-permutation-algorithm-explained-and-implemented-in-java/#comment-990) of how the Steinhaus Johnson Trotter algorithm works, and wanted to implement it faithfully in Javascript.

To do so, I created an object for each character in the string with a "direction" property that can be changed from left to right.

The code works, but it's like, impossibly long and pretty ugly (with nested if statements for example). I'd appreciate some pointers on how I could simplify it.

```
function permutations(string) {
    var letterArray = [];
    var permutSolution = [string];

    //Create objects for each character with initial position value and direction:
    function letter(char, pos, dir) {
        this.character = char;
        this.position = pos;
        this.direction = dir;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var newLetterObj = new letter(string[i], i, 'left');
        letterArray.push(newLetterObj);
    }

    //function to identify the highest mobile character
    function findHighestMC(value) {
        return value.position == i;
    }

    //change the direction of characters with a higher position value than the current highest mobile character
    function changeHigherMCDirection(element, index, array) {
        if (element.position > i && element.direction == 'left') {
            element.direction = 'right';
        }
        else if (element.position > i && element.direction == 'right') {
            element.direction = 'left';
        }
    }

    //run the algorithm through the input string
    for (i = string.length -1; i > -1; i--) {
        var highestMC = letterArray.filter(findHighestMC)[0]; //extract object from array
        var highestMCIndex = letterArray.indexOf(highestMC);
        if (highestMC.direction == 'left' && letterArray[highestMCIndex - 1] !== undefined && letterArray[highestMCIndex - 1].position < letterArray[highestMCIndex].position) {
            var swap = letterArray[highestMCIndex];
            letterArray[highestMCIndex] = letterArray[highestMCIndex - 1];
            letterArray[highestMCIndex - 1] = swap;
            var newPermut = letterArray.map(function(obj) {return obj.character;}).join('');
            permutSolution.push(newPermut);
            if (i == string.length - 1) {
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < string.length - 1) {
                letterArray.forEach(changeHigherMCDirection);
                i = string.length;
            }
        }
        else if (highestMC.direction == 'right' && letterArray[highestMCIndex + 1] !== undefined && letterArray[highestMCIndex + 1].position < letterArray[highestMCIndex].position) {
            var swap = letterArray[highestMCIndex];
            letterArray[highestMCIndex] = letterArray[highestMCIndex + 1];
            letterArray[highestMCIndex + 1] = swap;
            var newPermut = letterArray.map(function(obj) {return obj.character;}).join('');
            permutSolution.push(newPermut);
            if (i == string.length - 1) {
                i++;
            }
            else if (i < string.length - 1) {
                letterArray.forEach(changeHigherMCDirection);
                i = string.length;
            }
        }
    }

    //remove duplicates from solution in case letters in input string aren't all unique
    function deDupe (element, index, array) {
        return array.indexOf(element) == index;
    }
    permutSolution = permutSolution.filter(deDupe);

    return permutSolution;
}
console.log(permutations('abcd'))
```

Comment: If you have working code, but are looking for style/design feedback, [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) may be the place for you. But [take a look at their asking guidelines first](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) -- I've never tried posting there.

Comment: @JeremyBanks You should :)

Comment: Thanks @JeremyBanks, I will!